# XML file from SQL Server UTF-8 encoding without BOM

Tags: xml, sql-server-2019

I have a problem with saving an XML file in UTF-8 encoding without BOM. XML is generated in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2019.

I've been looking for an idea in various forums, but I can't find a solution.

The code presented below is truncated and shows only what is relevant from the point of view of my question.

```
DECLARE @OLE INT, @File varchar(300), @FileID INT
EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @OLE OUTPUT

DECLARE @Text XML
SET @Text = (
SELECT (SELECT S1 AS [BuyerOrderNumber]
            FROM Table1 where tday='94218'
            FOR XML PATH('OrderParty'), TYPE) AS 'InvoiceParty'
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Invoice'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)

DECLARE @Converted NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Converted = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @Text)
SET @Converted='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+@Converted
SET @File = '\\server\company\abc.xml'

EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty @OLE,'Charset','utf-8'
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,'Open'
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,'OpenTextFile',@FileID OUT,@File, 8, 0
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,'WriteText',NULL,@Converted

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,'SaveToFile',NULL,@File, 2
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,'Close'
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE
```

After running the procedure, the saved XML file in Notepad++ is in UTF-8-BOM encoding.

When I try to change the `sp_OASetProperty` parameter from 'utf-8' to 'utf-16' - I get an XML file saved with UTF-16 LE BOM encoding.

I need save XML file in UTF-8 encoding and I have to do in a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Could you help me?

Jacek

I tried the below solution by swapping the encoding but no effect:
https://www.example-code.com/sql/charset_add_utf8_bom_to_file.asp

Comment: Why not to use bcp.exe for the task?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU14) (KB5007182) - 15.0.4188.2 (X64)   Nov  3 2021 19:19:51   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it via **bcp.exe** SQL Server utility in T-SQL.

You may need to adjust some of the parameters:

- output file fully qualified path.
- bcp fully qualified path.
- etc.

**SQL**

```
/*
-T tells BCP to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server. It will operate as the user who's running the command.
-U <login_id> -P <password> tells BCP to use SQL Server account while connecting to SQL Server.
*/
DECLARE @SQLCmd VARCHAR(8000)
    , @outputFileName VARCHAR(256) = 'e:\Temp\SampleXMLOutput.xml'
    , @bcp VARCHAR(256) = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
    , @SQL VARCHAR(2048) = 'SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT TOP(2) TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM master.Information_Schema.Tables FOR XML PATH(''r''), TYPE, ROOT(''root'');'
    , @tcpPort VARCHAR(10) = '1433'
    , @WindowsAuth BIT = 1  -- 1 is for Windows Authentication, 0 is for SQL Server Authentication
    , @loginID VARCHAR(100) = 'loginID'
    , @password VARCHAR(100) = 'password'
    , @serverName VARCHAR(100) = 'machineName';

-- SQL Server 2016 onwards
-- /B "WindowTitle" parameters produce output in the SSSMS !!!
SET @SQLCmd = FORMATMESSAGE('START /B "WindowTitle" "%s" "%s" queryout "%s" %s -x -c -C 1252 -a 65535 -S "%s,%s"'
                , @bcp
                , @SQL
                , @outputFileName
                , IIF(@WindowsAuth = 1, '-T', ' -U '+ @loginID + ' -P ' + @password)
                , @@SERVERNAME
                , @tcpPort);

-- just to see it
SELECT @SQLCmd AS [Command to execute];

-- create file on the file system
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd;

/*
You may get this error:
Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure master..xp_cmdshell, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell', search for 'xp_cmdshell' in SQL Server Books Online.

Solution:
---- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
---- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
---- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
---- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
*/
```

Comment: Urgh, why use `xp_cmshell` to call bcp, why not just call it from a regular command prompt or Powershell. T-SQL is not a generalized scripting language, don't use it as such.

Comment: The OP needs it in T-SQL in a stored procedure. Overall, I agree with you.

Comment: Could even write a Powershell SQL Agent Job and fire it off.

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell and the [DbaTools module](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html), it's pretty easy to get an output.

```
$result = Invoke-DbaQuery `
  -SqlInstance 'MachineName\InstanceName'
  -Database 'YourDb'
  -As SingleValue
  -Query @"
SELECT (
    SELECT (
        SELECT S1 AS [BuyerOrderNumber]
        FROM Table1 where tday='94218'
        FOR XML PATH('OrderParty'), TYPE
    ) AS InvoiceParty
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Invoice'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
);
"@

$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + $result;

Out-File -FilePath '\\server\company\abc.xml' -Encoding UTF8;
```

If you want to trigger this from T-SQL, you can make a SQL Agent Job written in Powershell, and fire it off using `sp_start_job`.